# Как в таблице c текстом убрать пустоту , которую создают display:table-cell и white-space:normal?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Когда использую `display: table-cell` и `white-space: normal`, красная таблица растягивается и в её правой части образуется пустота. Как от этого избавиться? В качестве примера привёл ещё один код, где красная таблица не растянута.

Нужно чтобы текст был в одну строку, обрезался по ширине блока и ставились многоточия в конце обрезания текста.

```css
.ceneral_conteiner {
  background-color: grey;
}
.conteiner_right{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.conteiner_left{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
}
.con_item_left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 90px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align: top;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="ceneral_conteiner">
  <div class="conteiner_left">
     <div class="con_item_left"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="conteiner_right">
    <div style="width: 50%; 
                table-layout: fixed; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                text-overflow: clip; 
                white-space: normal; 
                display: block;">
      <div style="height: 30px; 
                  width: 50%; 
                  display: block; 
                  background-color: blue;
                  overflow: hidden;  
                  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
                  word-wrap: break-word; 
                  white-space: nowrap;">
        нннннrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyнннннrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Во втором коде текст не растягивает таблицу**

```css
.ceneral_conteiner {
  background-color: grey;
}
.conteiner_right{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: red;
  word-break: break-all;
}
.conteiner_left{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
}
.con_item_left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 90px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align: top;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="ceneral_conteiner">
  <div class="conteiner_left">
    <div class="con_item_left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="conteiner_right">
    3333333333333333333334кккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккцццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппп
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Юрий, поясните, как должен выглядеть результат? Что именно в первой таблице называете пустотой? Чем не устраивает второй код?

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky Вот, пожалуйста, я отредактировал свой вопрос, добавив необходимые детали.  Если что-то будет не понятно, я объясню, пишите.

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky `Чем не устраивает второй код?` - Нужно чтобы текст был в одну строку, обрезался по ширине блока и ставились многоточия в конце обрезания текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1. Блоки без `display:table-cell;`**

`text-overflow` работает внутри блока, у которого `overflow` установлено как `auto`, `scroll` или `hidden`. См. https://webref.ru/css/text-overflow

В связи с этим предлагаю решение без `display: table-cell;` и `white-space: normal;`. Такой вариант решает задачу?

```css
.ceneral_conteiner {
  background: red;
  height: 90px;
}
.conteiner_right {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.conteiner_left {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ceneral_conteiner">
  <div class="conteiner_left">
  </div>
  <div class="conteiner_right">
3333333333333333333334кккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккцццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццццккккккккккккккккккккккккккккккппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппп
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2. HTML-таблица**

Попробовал варианты и делаю вывод, что `text-overflow` работает для блока с `display:table-cell;`, если ширина блока задана в пикселях, и не работает, если ширина задана в процентах. Но если заменить блоки на стандартные табличные элементы, то проценты тоже вступают в игру.

```css
table {
  background: grey;
  border: 0 solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  vertical-align: top;
}
td {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td.td-left {
  background: green;
  width: 30px;
}
td.td-right {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="td-left">more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more</td>
  <td class="td-right">more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/e18qtjz0/

Comment: нужно именно с display: table-cell.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Попробовал варианты и делаю вывод, что `text-overflow` работает для блока с `display:table-cell;`, если ширина блока задана в пикселях, и не работает, если ширина задана в процентах. Но если заменить блоки на стандартные табличные элементы, то проценты тоже вступают в игру. Добавил в ответ пример кода.

Comment: Спасибо, но можно сделать и более хитро - `width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;`

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Попробовал https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/sqekq30p/ Многоточие не появляется. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Вот - https://jsfiddle.net/sqekq30p/3/

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Ух ты, спасибо! Пробовал заворачивать текст в блок, но без такого трюка это не срабатывало. После вашей подсказки нашёл его [на англоязычном оверфлоу](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932018/).